# The usage of words rancid, stale, putrid, decayed, rotten, spoiled, decomposed

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

Could you please compare these words in terms of meaning and daily usage in reference to only foods?

Could you give specific examples from daily life.For example which words can be used for bread, milk, yogurt, cheese, vegetables, fruits or cooked meals and the conditions in which food placed that the words suggest?

Comment: Looks awfully similar to your deleted question [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/64991/rancid-stale-moldy-musty-putrid-decayed-rotten-spoiled-decomposed-go-of). Please edit to make this more focused.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - Some research would be in order, too. It wouldn't hurt to add some definitions from a dictionary. P.S. Would love to have you in the moderator election, if you were inclined to run. You sure have left a lot of helpful, spot-on comments of late.

Comment: @J.R.: I appreciate the encouragement! I've been seriously considering it, to be honest.

Comment: @Nathan - You'd have my vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- *spoiled*  generally refers to food that needs to be thrown away
- *stale* refers to baked goods that are no longer fresh
- *rotten* refers to produce like fruits and vegatables, although it can occasionally be used with meats
- *decayed* and *decomposed* refer to items are partly rotted away;  you might use these words to describe the carcass of an animal
- *rancid* and *putrid* are words usually used when there is a terrible smell.

The first four words are used often to describe food. The last four words occasional describe food (*rancid meat*, e.g.), but are probably used to describe garbage more than food.

Comment: With *rancid* I immedialy think of fats and oils.